# "Undefined" appears on side of document after alert box triggers

Tags: javascript, html, button, alert

I've been making a website where if you click a button an alert box pops up. But after I click the button the word "undefined" appears on the side of my document.

The way that I have been doing it is like this:

```html
<button onclick="run()">Click me</button>
<span id="no"></span>
<script>
function no() {
document.getElementById("no").innerHTML = alert("This is an alert box");
}
</script>
```

For some reason, after I click the button, the words "undefined" appear on the document. As you can see if you run the snippet, once you click one of the "buy" buttons, if you scroll down to the bottom of the product page, you will see the word "undefined" on the left. Should I not be using this method?

```js
function purchase() {
  document.getElementById("no").innerHTML = alert("Sorry, but we're all sold out! Try again later.");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
  <title>Buy stuff at a high price!</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn.hipwallpaper.com/i/63/61/AykYVG.png">
</head>

<body>

  <style>
    center.mission {
      font-family: serrif;
      font-size: 180%;
      background-color: rgb(100, 200, 0);
      LINE-HEIGHT: 1;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: rgb(196, 255, 196);
    }
  </style>


  <!--Our products-->
  <p>
    </br>
    <center class="products">
      <h1>OUR PRODUCTS</h1>
    </center>
    <center>
      <h3>NO RETURNS</h3>
    </center>
    <br/>
    <div id="column1">Single sheet 8.5"/11" printer paper
      <br/>
      <img src="https://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/blank-paper-background.jpg" height="150px" width="350px" />
      <button onclick="purchase()">BUY NOW FOR $19.99</button>
    </div>
    <div id="column2">Single sheet 8.5"/11" printer paper(pre-crumpled)
      <br/>
      <center><img src="https://149351503.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/paper_71_closed.png" height="150px" width="200px" /></center>
      <button onclick="purchase()">BUY NOW FOR $34.99</button>
    </div>
    <div id="column3">Single CD-R disc, scratched
      <br/>
      <img src="https://i.redd.it/akbvkcw2xgmz.jpg" height="150px" width="250px" />
      <br/>
      <button onclick="purchase()">BUY NOW FOR $42.99</button>
    </div>
    <style>
      center.products {
        color: green;
        background-color: purple;
      }
      
      div {
        float: left;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 0 10px;
      }
      
      #column1 {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        width: 30%;
      }
      
      #column2 {
        background-color: grey;
        width: 30%;
      }
      
      #column3 {
        background-color: darkgrey;
        width: 30%;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="column4">Single toilet paper square for quarentine days
      <br/>
      <img src="https://photos1.blogger.com/blogger/7265/3234/1600/napkin.jpg" height="150px" width="250px" />
      <button onclick="purchase()">BUY NOW FOR $12.99</button>
    </div>
    <div id="column5">Single use toothpick
      <br/>
      <center><img src="https://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1sYpPQpXXXXcPXXXXq6xXFXXXu.jpg" height="150px" width="300px" /></center>
      <button onclick="purchase()">BUY NOW FOR $6.99</button>
    </div>
    <div id="column6">10cm dental floss
      <br/>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Dental_floss_%28whole%29.jpg" height="150px" width="250px" />
      <br/>
      <button onclick="purchase()">BUY NOW FOR $339.99</button>
    </div>
    <style>
      center.products {
        color: green;
        background-color: purple;
      }
      
      div {
        float: left;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 0 10px;
      }
      
      #column4 {
        background-color: darkgrey;
        width: 30%;
      }
      
      #column5 {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        width: 30%;
      }
      
      #column6 {
        background-color: grey;
        width: 30%;
      }
    </style>

    <!--For click events-->
    <span id="no"></span>

</body>

</html>
```

Is there any way to stop this from happening without changing my method? I apologize that it is so messy, it's not meant to be run on the stack overflow snippet creator.

NOTE: This website isn't meant to be professional. In fact, it's meant to be poorly designed. That's why I'm using the `<center>` attribute.

Comment: Just a small nitpick, you've misspelled serif and why is line-height capitalized in your CSS? Also, the center tag is long since deprecated. Side note, 1 sheet of toilet paper for $12.99 is sadly hilarious these days. The new gold standard.

Comment: @Phix I'm trying to make my website look really, really bad, so I don't care what kind of alignment I use. The capitalization hasn't effected the website as far as I can tell. Thanks for the tip about serif.

Comment: That's amazing. CSS and HTML are case insensitive so whatever :) @ me with a link when it's done.

Comment: @Phix here's the link: www.wewillsellyoucrap.com I would prefer if you opened it on a computer, not on a phone or tablet, because those views haven't been set up yet.

Comment: That's glorious!

Comment: @Phix Thanks! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you like to set innerHTML of element to alert?

```js
function purchase() {
  alert("Sorry, but we're all sold out! Try again later.");
}
```

```html
<!--Copyright 2020 AWOL Industries International. All rights reserved-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
  <title>Buy stuff at a high price!</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn.hipwallpaper.com/i/63/61/AykYVG.png">
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1 style="color:red; background-color:black">AWOL INDUSTRIES INTERNATIONAL</h1>
  </center>


  <style>
    center.mission {
      font-family: serrif;
      font-size: 180%;
      background-color: rgb(100, 200, 0);
      LINE-HEIGHT: 1;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: rgb(196, 255, 196);
    }
  </style>


  <!--Our products-->
  <p>
    </br>
    <center class="products">
      <h1>OUR PRODUCTS</h1>
    </center>
    <center>
      <h3>NO RETURNS</h3>
    </center>
    <br/>
    <div id="column1">Single sheet 8.5"/11" printer paper
      <br/>
      <img src="https://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/blank-paper-background.jpg" height="150px" width="350px" />
      <button onclick="purchase()">BUY NOW FOR $19.99</button>
    </div>
    <div id="column2">Single sheet 8.5"/11" printer paper(pre-crumpled)
      <br/>
      <center><img src="https://149351503.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/paper_71_closed.png" height="150px" width="200px" /></center>
      <button onclick="purchase()">BUY NOW FOR $34.99</button>
    </div>
    <div id="column3">Single CD-R disc, scratched
      <br/>
      <img src="https://i.redd.it/akbvkcw2xgmz.jpg" height="150px" width="250px" />
      <br/>
      <button onclick="purchase()">BUY NOW FOR $42.99</button>
    </div>
    <style>
      center.products {
        color: green;
        background-color: purple;
      }
      
      div {
        float: left;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 0 10px;
      }
      
      #column1 {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        width: 30%;
      }
      
      #column2 {
        background-color: grey;
        width: 30%;
      }
      
      #column3 {
        background-color: darkgrey;
        width: 30%;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="column4">Single toilet paper square for quarentine days
      <br/>
      <img src="https://photos1.blogger.com/blogger/7265/3234/1600/napkin.jpg" height="150px" width="250px" />
      <button onclick="purchase()">BUY NOW FOR $12.99</button>
    </div>
    <div id="column5">Single use toothpick
      <br/>
      <center><img src="https://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1sYpPQpXXXXcPXXXXq6xXFXXXu.jpg" height="150px" width="300px" /></center>
      <button onclick="purchase()">BUY NOW FOR $6.99</button>
    </div>
    <div id="column6">10cm dental floss
      <br/>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Dental_floss_%28whole%29.jpg" height="150px" width="250px" />
      <br/>
      <button onclick="purchase()">BUY NOW FOR $339.99</button>
    </div>
    <style>
      center.products {
        color: green;
        background-color: purple;
      }
      
      div {
        float: left;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 0 10px;
      }
      
      #column4 {
        background-color: darkgrey;
        width: 30%;
      }
      
      #column5 {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        width: 30%;
      }
      
      #column6 {
        background-color: grey;
        width: 30%;
      }
    </style>

    <!--For click events-->
    <span id="no"></span>

</body>

</html>
```

This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The `alert` method in javascript returns no value, which in javascript is `undefined`.

You're setting the `span` inner html to that value

```
document.getElementById("no").innerHTML = alert("Sorry, but we're all sold out! Try again later.");
```

I'm curious what you think the above line did.

Comment: I'm not sure what your solution is. Can you please make it a little more clear?

Comment: @LemmyX What Jamiec is saying is you're trying to set the innerHTML to the result of a function that returns `undefined`. Either you want to just set the innerHTML to the string in the alert function or just alert and not set the innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, any undefined variable (or property) is `undefined` (which is a type, like `String`, `Object`, `Date`, `null`, etc). When this result is coerced into a string, it appears as the actual string "undefined". Try these in your browser's console to get a feel for it:

```
console.log(foo);
console.log(window.foo);
console.log(String(window.foo));
```

When you assign the `innerHTML` property of your div to the result of the [alert function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) (which doesn't return anything, and therefore a value of `undefined`), you're coercing it into the string "undefined" and setting that to be the innerHTML of the div. What is your actual intended behavior?

Comment: I just want an alert box, no string.

Comment: Then why are you doing this? `document.getElementById("no").innerHTML = `

Comment: I was using a template where it used `document.write();` instead of alert.